# ASP.NET / IIS7 Url Rewrite maps not working

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting

I've followed the instructions [Learn IIS's webpage](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/469/using-rewrite-maps-in-url-rewrite-module/) for adding static redirects with a rewrite map for my asp.net application.

The following is the config:

```xml
<rule name="Redirect rule1 for Information" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{Information:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

And

```xml
<rewriteMaps>
    <rewriteMap name="Information">
        <add key="/Information/CorporateSales.aspx"
             value="/KB/Information/CorporateSales" />
        <add key="/Information/ComputerRepair.aspx"
             value="/KB/Information/ComputerRepair" />
    </rewriteMap>
</rewriteMaps>
```

This was even originally created by the wizard in IIS's manager for using rewrite maps.

So the idea is that `/Information/CorporateSales.aspx` --> `/KB/Information/CorporateSales` with a 301 redirect (MOVED PERMANENTLY).

However I'm just getting the original aspx page (Which we're removing later) loading. I've even **deleted the file** incase it was defaulting to an existing resource, and with that i just get a plain 404 without the redirect.

Anyone have an idea?

**Let me clarify something:**

Rewrite module *works*, it's installed and running. My standard regex rules work nicely. But my **rewrite map** does not.

Answer (score 8):

This article http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-rewrite-maps-in-url-rewrite-module and code below worked for me.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect rule1 for RedirectURLs">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{RedirectURLs:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
    <rewriteMaps>
        <rewriteMap name="RedirectURLs">
            <add key="/privacy.php" value="/privacy" />
        </rewriteMap>
    </rewriteMaps>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 3):

I was having a similar problem and found this question.  It took me a little while, but I was able to figure out what the problem was.

My rewriteMap contained the urls "/Default2.aspx" and "/Dashboard.aspx".

When I would go to Default2.aspx, I would get a 404 rather than get redirected to Dashboard.aspx as expected.

The issue I found was that on my machine, the application was running in a subdirectory.  The rewriteMap paths would only work if I used the full path (including the application folder), e.g., "/TestSite/Default2.aspx".

So I could have added duplicate entries in my rewriteMap to account for application directories on developer machines, but that seemed messy.  I looked at the other rewrite rules in the application that did not have this issue and I noticed that they were using the {REQUEST_FILENAME} variable, rather than {REQUEST_URI}.  So I switched the rule to use {REQUEST_FILENAME} and remove the first slash from the urls in my rewriteMap.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Url rewriting installed as part of IIS7/7.5? This is not installed by default. Also, make sure your app pool is set to integrated pipline mode, no classic.

**Edit**

From this:

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/469/using-rewrite-maps-in-url-rewrite-module/

This only thing I see that you're doing is adding the 'stopProcessing' attribute. Have you tried removing that?

Comment: It is installed and Integrated

Answer (score 0):

Previously I had same problem as you described.

Could you update your code to

```
<match url="(.*)" />
```

and I hope you aware,

```
 <add input="{Information:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
```

this condition will capture full URL except the domain.
example on this url:
`www.example.com/Information/CorporateSales.aspx`
it will check matching condition of 
`Information/CorporateSales.aspx` on rewriteMap

and for sure it wont be match with this url

`www.example.com/old/Information/CorporateSales.aspx`

Answer (score -5):

Did you reset the app pool and the iis site ?

In some cases it can take up to 72 hours (iirc) to propagate throughout the world.

Comment: This is a local dev machine, and i've reset not only the app pool, but all of iis as well.