# IIS Rewrite Map not working

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I'm rebuilding a site using `iis urlrewriting` on both static and dynamic pages. The redirects are all working well. The rewrite module is working perfectly.

Since the site structure is changing, I need to be able to redirect "old" defunct urls to new pages. So, for example, *www.sitename.com/research.asp* needs to be redirected to *www.sitename.com/news*

I've followed the instructions to set up a rule using a rewrite map and placed the rule near the top of my webconfig file (just under the CanonicalHostNameRule). But whatever permutations I've tried in the rule, I just can get it to work. The redirects don't happen - I just get a 404 for the (non-existent) .asp page. The map just seems to be getting ignored entirely. Just to re-iterate, all my other rules are working fine.

I've tried turning off all other rules and just working with this one, but no luck.  Equally, I've trawled this forum and others for suggestions (using REQUEST_URI rather than Filename, restarting IIS, recycling App. Pools, etc etc), but nothing seems to work. The "Redirect" url="{C:1}" just sends me back to the old asp page I'm trying to get redirected away from, if that makes sense. Nothing in FailedRequestTracing seems to help, either.

Am I missing something very obvious here?

The Rule:

```
<rule name="Redirect Rule" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{StaticRedirects:{REQUEST_FILENAME}}" pattern="(.+)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

The Map:

```
<rewriteMaps>
    <rewriteMap name="StaticRedirects">
        <add key="research.asp" value="news" />
        <add key="blog.asp" value="news" />
        <add key="mentors.asp" value="interviews" />
        <add key="regulars.asp" value="opinion" />
    </rewriteMap>
</rewriteMaps>
```

NB - there are lots of other static redirects to add to this once it actually works, which is why I wanted to use a map.

Comment: Can I suggest comparing to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22050145/48348? This one was the minimum setup that worked for me. Then I customised from there once it was all working.